# Adding custom jar dependency to module in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have an android project contains a module.
I added a library named lib to the project, then I added a jar (jar I have created in an other project).
then clicked file --> project structure --> choose my module --> dependencies --> added a jar dependency.
When I try to create the apk I get the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have tried to change the scope dependency to provided, which did not helped,
Also I have tried to create new module the have a dependency in the jar, that did not work.

my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myprj"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    'com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.18.1'
    'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.18.1'
    'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:1.1.1'
    'com.owlike:genson:0.99'
    provided files('libs/MyJar.jar')
}
```

any suggestions?

## UPDATE

I solved my problem, the other jar was compiled with java 1.8 settings, I changed it to 1.7 and recreated the jar, that solved my problem.

Comment: post your build.gradle files,and the full stacktrace of your gradle error

Comment: delete project cache.... and try again

Comment: 1. I have edited the post to contains the build.gradle. 2. I tried to clear the cache, it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
provided files('libs/MyJar.jar')
```

You're already including every .jar in libs directory a couple of lines above:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: thank for your answer, It almost worked for me, I had to changed the compile to provided.

Comment: That means the .jar won't be deployed with your app. If you call any code from the .jar, you'll get ClassNotFound exceptions. Is it some sort of code processor?

Answer (score 0):

The error above means that you have a duplicated library being used upon 
compile time.

Always and only use the `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` when adding a library in gradle and never add another instance of the same library which you did in `provided files('libs/MyJar.jar')`.